# How to remove close button from Bulma modal card title?

Tags: css, bulma

The [Bulma css for modal](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/) adds an automatic close button `x` befor the `Modal Title`

```
   <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-background"></div>
      <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
          <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
          <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
          <!-- Content ... -->
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
          <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
          <button class="button">Cancel</button>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm wondering how can I remove it whitout recompiling the whole thing?

Comment: According to the documentation, you should be able to remove the close button just by deleting this line (in the example code of Bulma) `<button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just comment or remove the line here and it will get rid of the X button

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal is-active">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <!--<button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button> -->
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      <!-- Content ... -->
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```